# Htaccess to remove backslash and Inverted comma

Tags: .htaccess

I have searched a lot, but could not find info or solution to it

a) is there any way to remove backslash in url through htaccess
There are some url which are having backslash after domain
like www.abc.com/\index.php

b) How to remove invert comma in url through htaccess "

Incorrect url

```
 http://www.abc.com/%5C%22/index.php?option=com_loan             or
 http://www.abc.com/\"/index.php?option=com_loan       or
 http://www.abc.com/%5C"/index.php?option=com_loan "
```

Correct url

```
 http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_loan
```

Many thanks

Comment: When did URLs start having back slashes in them?

Comment: its coming in some of them as reported in webmaster

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+.+?(/index\.php\?[^\s]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, a similar query was asked post a week on - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270748/robots-excluding-url-with-special-character - which later on solved by rewriting the same way through htaccess

Comment: I saw that link. YOu merely commented there that you solved by mod_rewrite rather than robots.txt That exactly is my solution here. If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted".