# Robots Excluding url with special character

Tags: robots.txt, duplicates

Look for recommendation as pertains to robots.txt and we dont want to go wrong in excluding the entire site

Is the below command apt for excluding all url with backslash encoded in url

```
 Disallow: /*\
```

Will it only exclude url's having backslash or %22 in the site url path. There are some pages been indexed with backslash and coming in as duplicate in Google webmaster.

Does the above command does not hinder or block site to search engines in any or either way except for url with backslash to it

Answer (score 0):

To update, we resolved it by rather applying 301 redirect through htaccess rather than blocking through robots.txt